# using semaphores from multiple files C-Windows

Tags: c, windows, semaphore

I want to use semaphores for "consumer-producer" problem using C in windows.
in file (afile.c) I globally declared a handle to semaphore:

```
HANDLE empty;
```

in the same file (afile.c), inside one of the functions, I created the semaphore:

```
empty = CreateSemaphore(NULL,size, size, NULL);
```

and used it in some functions. after finished using, i relesed it using:

```
ReleaseSemaphore(empty,1,NULL);
```

I want to use this semaphore in another file (bfile.c), so i included (afile.h) in (bfile.c)

```
#include "afile.h"
```

bfile.c cant recognize this semaphore.

any suggestions for solving this problem, or, help in undestanding how to make use of semaphores from multiple files?

Comment: maybe `extern` will help you?

Comment: If you need to use it in several files because that's somehow a sound program design, then each file needs a function which takes the semaphore as parameter, and you leave the creation of it to the caller. Resorting to spaghetti `extern` means your program design is broken.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't quite get what you mean. can be more specific please?

Comment: @a_beilis No, because I don't know what "afile" and "bfile" are supposed to be, it's all too abstract. Generally each file should contain a "class"/ADT, and that class should be autonomous, with private encapsulation, without exposing internals to other files. So the first question you should ask yourself is how it makes sense for "bfile" to access the semaphore, program design-wise.

Comment: @Lundin afile is the producer module and bfile is the consumer module. they are different threads. the semaphore is used in order to manage both of them

Comment: Why aren't they in the same file then?

Comment: because it's a good practice to divide my program into modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In afile.c you should have:

```
HANDLE empty = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

In afile.h you should have:

```
extern HANDLE empty;
```